# Bash metaprogramming

Tags: bash, arguments, metaprogramming, command-line-arguments, cartesian-product

I have a script that takes commands (for the script, not for bash) as arguments.

It treats the two invocations below the same:

```
$ ./my_script -f 'cmd1','cmd2','cmd3' #etc
$ ./my_script -f 'cnd1' -f 'cmd2' -f'cmd3' #etc
```

A frequent use case for the script would have it take commands of the same family, but with different arguments or flags:

```
$ ./my_script -f 'cmd arg1','cmd arg2','cmd arg3'
```

I would like to be able to type that in succinctly, essentially as a Cartesian product of `{"'cmd "}` `{arg1,arg2,arg3,...}`, each followed by "'"`

I know bash can do cartesian products, and indeed:

```
$ echo "-f 'cmd "{arg1,arg2,arg3}"'"
```

outputs the second part of my invocation in the second form:

```
 -f 'cmd arg1' -f 'cmd arg2' -f 'cmd arg3'
```

However, if used in the invocation like this:

```
$ ./my_script "-f 'cmd "{1,2,3}"'"
```

the script of course sees it  as 3 arguments with spaces in them. If I echo the Cartesian product part in a subshell as follows:

```
$ ./my_script $(echo "-f 'cmd "{1,2,3}"'")
```

then it'll split on each space, ignoring the single quotation marks.

Using a ruby one-liner to illustrate how the script receives the params in each case:

```
$ ruby -e  'puts ARGV.each_with_index.map {|a,i| (i+1).to_s+" : "+a}' --  "-f 'cmd "{1,2,3}"'"
1 : -f 'cmd 1'
2 : -f 'cmd 2'
3 : -f 'cmd 3'

$ ruby -e  'puts ARGV.each_with_index.map {|a,i| (i+1).to_s+" : "+a}' --  $(echo "-f 'cmd "{1,2,3}"'")                                                                                                                            
1 : -f
2 : 'cmd
3 : 1'
4 : -f
5 : 'cmd
6 : 2'
7 : -f
8 : 'cmd
9 : 3'
```

So my question is, can I get bash to evaluate the output of the `echo` command as if it were typed in by the user? (process quotation marks and everything?)

**Update**:

I should have mentioned that the script takes other params that can have spaces in them, so in fact I was looking for some kind of *partial*, localized `eval` (if there is such a thing), as otherwise I'd have to escape the other quotation marks for them to get through to `eval`.

(If not, I'll just add the Cartesian product capability to the script, but I felt like making sure that there isn't an elegant way to do it from outside.)

Comment: For quasiquoting in bash land, `printf "%q"` is a must-have-read in the manpage

Answer (score 3):

That's where you need an extra step of `eval`:

This resembles your ruby script (without the counting):

```
f() {
  for arg
  do
    echo "[$arg]"
  done
}
```

And this is how you then call this:

```
eval f "-f 'cmd "{1,2,3}"'"
```

The output is the expected:

```
[-f]
[cmd 1]
[-f]
[cmd 2]
[-f]
[cmd 3]
```